# React Dynamic meta tags

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter, meta-tags

I am using Reactjs and codeigniter APIs but the problem is in react side. Here is the reactjs meta tags code which rendered when a new page load and get API response. The content of meta tags is updating but in the meta preview apps it is not shwoing the data.

```
          <Helmet>
            <title>{data.page_title}</title>
            <meta name="title" content={site_settings.site_name} />
            <meta name="description" content={meta_desc.meta_description} />
            <meta name="keywords" content={meta_desc.meta_keywords} />
            <meta property="og:title" content={meta_desc.og_title} />
            <meta
              property="og:descripiton"
              content={meta_desc.og_description}
            />
            <meta property="og:url" content={window.location.href} />
            <meta
              property="og:image"
              content={`${site_settings.site_domain}api/uploads/images/${site_settings.site_logo}`}
            />
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
          </Helmet>
```

[Html head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oieV.png)

[Meta preview apps response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyX7p.png)

I have used React Helmet, React Document Meta etc npm libraries. but it is not working. Is there a solution that would work without SSR? Or an easy solution with SSR?

Comment: Why you don't use Next js? it has better options for SEO and meta tags.

Comment: Is this a question about react or PHP?  When posting a question, include your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will surely use nextjs next time. but right now the project is developed in reactjs and site is live. I need a solution in reactjs.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, thanks for your guide I tried to update the question in more detail

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.